# using matrix to rotate bitmap result zoom

Tags: android

when i use matrix to rotate the bitmap. the bitmap rotated but it is zoomed ,when i remove the angle and put the matrix only to the bitmap it bitmap is zoomed.
i found that the matrix result that the bitmap is zoom

```
 int rotation = 90;

            Matrix matrix=new Matrix();
              matrix
           // matrix.postRotate(rotation);
            Bitmap bn=Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap,0, 0,200, 200, matrix, false);
            ImageView b=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            b.setImageBitmap(bn);
```

without angle

```
        Matrix matrix=new Matrix();
        Bitmap bn=Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap,0, 0,200, 200, matrix, false);
        ImageView b=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        b.setImageBitmap(bn);
```

Comment: I doubt that the matrix causes the zoom. What ScaleType do you have on the `ImageView`?

Comment: i use matrix to the bitmap i did not use any scale to the image view